# undertow connection closed in spring boot project

Tags: json, spring-boot, axios, http-post, undertow

I am working with spring boot project using undertow as web server. My client side application uses axios to make post request to my project. The request has json data type as parameter. However, I sometimes get error below about 5 times per day. My client application makes about 1,000,000 requests per day.

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: UT000128: Remote peer closed connection before all data could be read
```

I can't find any document about handling 'UT000128: Remote peer closed connection before all data could be read'error. Is there anyone who could give me some advice? Thanks in advance.